# Handle overlay click using stopevents to false

Tags: openlayers-3, angular-openlayers

- I have a web app based on angular-js and openlayers3
- I have an overlay (popup) with "stopEvent : false"
- I have set an ng-click on an element inside that overlay

The event is correctly fired on desktop (even with smartphones resolution, so the css and the possible overlap of html elements is not a problem), but on android phones that event is not fired.

Do you have suggestions about this problem?